# Populating two drop down lists based on selection of item in 1st dropdownlist and in 2nd dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I have three drop down list ddl1, ddl2 and ddl3.

Now on selecting an item of ddl1 the respective items in ddl2 and similarly ddl3 should be populated.

Eg:- If I select "India" in ddl1 then ddl2 should display all states and ddl3 should display all cities of country India. I wish to do this without any database connectivity( using Jquery ). Please help!!!. Thanks.

Comment: if you find an answer useful, you should mark it correct :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with a reasonable amount of data you can code it into a javascript object and use that to populate your dropdowns. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KW7hM/3/).

```
var data = { 
  "India": { 
    "Cities" : ["Mumbai", "Delhi", "Bangalore"],
    "States" : ["Bihar", "Goa", "Hayana"] },
  "Japan": {
    "Cities" : ["Tokyo", "Kyoto", "Nagoya"],
    "States" : ["Miyagi", "Nara", "Tottori"] }
}
```

The way you populate a select using jQuery is going to be roughly the same across the board.

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    $('#ddl1').append($('<option>', {
        value: key
    }).text(key));
});

$('#ddl1').change(function () {
    //empty lists 2 and 3
    $('#ddl2').html("");
    $('#ddl3').html("");

    var option_selected = $('option:selected', this).val();

    //populate ddl2
    $.each(data[option_selected]['Cities'], function (index, element) {
        $('#ddl2').append($('<option>', {
            value: element
        }).text(element));
    });

    //populate ddl3
    $.each(data[option_selected]['States'], function (index, element) {
        $('#ddl3').append($('<option>', {

            value: element
        }).text(element));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no database connectivity, then you need to prepopulate all possible options on the page using arrays or json strings or hidden dropdowns.

That'll make your page a bit heavy, but anyway you could have in javascript

```
countryOptions = {"Armenia", "Albania"....};

IndiaStates = {"State1", "State2"};
USAStates = {...};
/* All state dropdowns for all possible countries */

IndiaCities  = {...};
USACities  = {...};
BelgiumCities  = {...};
```

Then a function

```
function populateDropdown(dropdownId, myOptions)
{
  $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    $("#" + dropdownId).append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
  });
}
```

And a changeEvent

```
$("#countryDropwDown").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == "India")
   {
      populateDropdown("StateDropDown", IndiaStates);
   }
});
```

And you do this for all countries.

A Smarter solution would be to use a naming convention

XCountry, XState, XCity and then use this convention to append the right dropdown list depending on the prefix X.